# How to set the learning rate in scikit-learn's ridge regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm using `scikit-learn`'s ridge regression:

```
regr = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = 0.5)

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#bias:
print('bias: \n', regr.intercept_)
# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

I found ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)) the different options for the `linear_model.Ridge` function, but there is a specific option that I didn't find in the list: How could I set the `learning rate` (or `learning step`) of the update function?

By `learning rate`, I mean:

w_{t+1} = w_t + (learning_rate) * (partial derivative of objective function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to learning rate as step size.

Your code is not using the sag (stochastic average gradient) solver. The default parameter for solver is set to `auto`, which will choose a solver depending on the data type. A description of the other solvers and which to use is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html).

To use the sag solver:

```
regr = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = 0.5, solver = 'sag')
```

However, for this solver you do not set the step size because the solver computes the step size based on your data and alpha. [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py) is the code for sag solver used for ridge regression, where they explain how the step size is computed.

> > > The step size is set to 1 / (alpha_scaled + L + fit_intercept) where L is
> > >           the max sum of squares for over all samples.

[Line 401](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py#L392) shows how sag_solver being used for ridge regression.

Comment: Thanks so much! But then, it seems to be using a step size only for SAG, and not for the "regular" (i.e., batch) Gradient Descent. Is  there a reason why?